# What are the differences between em and % in terms of text resizing and for fixed width site? Is em more hyped than %?

Tags: css, xhtml

What are the differences between `em` and `%` in terms of text resizing and for fixed width site? 
If I'm using `em` or `%` only for text sizing in a fixed width site and 
body is set as

```
{body:font-size:100%}
```

and what is these best practice to use in css for text sizing for fixed width in terms of accessibility and mobile device friendlies?

What is the difference between % and em for using `ctrl + 0` to resizing text in browser?

Which is better and why one should be used over another? What is the problem with `%` and what i the benefit of `em`

please give explain with live example .

Answer (score 2):

Both are ways of specifying  *relative* measures. The difference lies in **what** are they relative to.

`%` is relative to the container

`em` is relative to the font size

So for a practical example check this `em` [example](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/063/063.css) and increase the font size (CTRL and +), you'll see that the divs that contain the text increase their size too.

In this other [page](http://www.csszengarden.com/), when you do the same, the div's don't increase they size.

[source](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=EmVsPercentWidths)

Comment: can u explain what is the means "Em is always relative to font size. % is relative to the containing block"

Comment: but ur first example link is fluid layout and i'm talking about fixed width layout

Comment: and in firefox in both example div's are increasing along with text size

Comment: recent browsers resize all text (and images) regardless of how they were specified. This is not "technically" correct, but is more useful.

Comment: @cobol - then if recent browsers resize all text (and images) regardless of how they were specified. then no difference between % and em and px

Comment: There IS a difference. The fact that some browsers ignore the difference and do otherwise is another thing

Comment: In Firefox 3.6 I can see the difference between use em or % that @Pablo said. The middle div is smaller relatively to its text.

Answer (score 0):

An `em` comes from the typographical term of the same name.  It is the width of the letter 'm' in the current font.  If you set a width to, say, `10em`, then the width *will be fixed* at 10 times the width of an 'm'.

`%` is a number of hundredths of a whole.  It describes a size that is dependent on its potential maximum.  So, assuming a simple web page viewed in a browser window, with no columns or anything, a width of `50%` means half (50/100) of the width of the window.  The actual width *will change with the width of the window.*  If you printed the page out, then the width changes to half the width of the printable area on the paper.

Which one you use depends on whether or not you need the dimension in question to adjust with window size.  If you need it to adjust, use `%`.  If you need it to remain a fixed dimension, use `em`.

EDIT: Ah, relating to the `font-size` descriptor.  Referring to some [online docs](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/font-size) I use, `font-size` with a `%` makes the font size relative to its parent.  What's the parent of `body`?  A good question that my reference doesn't answer.  I would assume it's either a higher-level specifier (i.e. one that would be overridden) in the CSS, or the document default.

As for `em`, that one takes the length in ems (as defined above) and converts that to a font size (by, say, converting to mm then to points).  Since most fonts don't have an em equal to the line height, I wouldn't expect `1em` to mean the same as `100%`.

Comment: can u give any example for both condition?

Comment: but if we set body{font-size:100%} then em and % both will scale

Comment: @Mike D. - I think Jitendra is talking about the differences between `em` & `%` with regards to `font-size`